# What percent of the mass the proton comes from its electric field energy density?

Tags: electromagnetism, mass, standard-model, quarks, protons

How much heavier would the proton be with respect to the neutron if the up quark and the down quark had the same mass?
How much does the electric field energy density of the proton contribute to its mass?

Comment: It's complicated: [Pagels 1966](https://journals.aps.org/pr/abstract/10.1103/PhysRev.144.1261).

Comment: [West 1980](https://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007/978-1-4613-3165-0_16). The current quarks' masses themselves differ by 2.5MeV, however....

Comment: Let me mention [arXiv:1406.4088](https://arxiv.org/abs/1406.4088) to add a slightly more recent discussion.  While the first line of Table 1 provides a numerical answer to these questions (reporting that the d-u quark mass difference provides ~2.5MeV to the neutron--proton mass difference while electromagnetism provides ~-1MeV, both with ~10% uncertainties), this result relies on specifying a convention for separating the electromagnetic and quark-mass contributions, discussed further in Section 10.3 of the Supplementary Material.